# Windows + php + schtasks = folder/file name mismatch or action not found

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

I am setting custom schtasks in windows using php to write and execute .bat files like this one:
schtasks /create /tn "RA AUTOMATIC BACKUP" /tr "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\MBM Software\Apache\htdocs\ra\automatic_backup\scriptspg_backup.bat\"" /ru "ProiectIM3" /rp "parola1" /sc minute /mo 1

The touble starts now:
1) if i don't use "\" after /tr the schedule tasks has the action: C:\Program Files and the rest is viewed like an argument
2) if i use "\" the schedule has the right action written: 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MBM Software\Apache\htdocs\ra\automatic_backup\scripts\pg_backup.bat" (quotes included)
BUT it will not run, on the other hand if i click on browse, set up the same file the action becomes 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MBM Software\Apache\htdocs\ra\automatic_backup\scripts\pg_backup.bat" (quotes included) and IT RUNS so the paths are EXACTLY the same but will not run with the first.

I am out of ideeas.

Answer (score 0):

what is your OS and OS language? the /SC parameter is language-specific on old OSes. I.e. it is MINUTO, not MINUTE on Portuguese Windows XP. Also, try to include computer or domain name in the user's name